# Can't split string with values that have in-text comma csv

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am using this regex `,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)` which is tried and proven by many and by myself as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/J3P6xQ/1).

However, when I use it to split a `.csv` file, it keeps giving an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on the `.split()` it is used in. The previous split before it had no issue. This is my code:

```
package csvsplit;


import java.io.IOException;


import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class FreqMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
    
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        
        if(key.get()==0) {
            return;
        }else {
            
            String line = value.toString();
            Text channel_name = new Text(line.split(",")[3]); //it splits perfectly
            IntWritable likes = new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")[8])); //arrayindexoutofboundsexception happens here
            context.write(channel_name, likes);
        }
        
        
    }
    
}
```

A pic of the error:
[image: error]

Any idea how to prevent it from doing so? Thank you for reading.

UPDATE:
[image: update]

The regex works. And I can loop through the results of the `split()`.

Comment: I don't think this error is thrown because of any issue in regex. It is because of [8] that you are using.Probably the array "split()", is returning does not contains 8+ elements, that's why it is throwingIndexOutOfBounds Exception. This means 'line' does not have enough numbers.

Comment: So the regex works fine, I agree. I am able to print out the elements after the `split()`and access them via for loop or println out by accessing the index directly. Odd.

Comment: Are you able to access the value of 8th index of that array too?

Comment: Yes, my update shows that i am able to loop through it. I do need to mention that when I println the value, I added in System.exit(-1) after it to show the value.